# Can't adjust the size of the system tray display area in Kubuntu 16.04(Plasma 5.9.5)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, panel, system-tray, plasma-5

I have wanted to adjust the size of the following area(I don't know what you people call it) ever since I started customizing Plasma 5(since a week, to be frank).
[image]

I have managed to make it something like this:
[image]

But after a reboot, log out or resizing the virtual machine window(yeah right, I am running it inside a VM), the size reverts to the former state.

Can anyone tell me how to make the change permanent?

Comment: Anyone, please!

Comment: I resized it by alt+right, but even that isn't working anymore...